# Json data caught as null but the data appear on screen

Tags: json, flutter, dart

im using dropdown widget and i getting the value from dummy json, when i press the value it return null but it appear in the menu.

this is the setState

```
  items: dropdownValueList2.map((e) {
          // var index = widget.data['option'].indexOf(e);
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            value: e['value'],
            child: Text(e['value']),
          );
        }).toList(),
        value: dropdownValue,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = value;
            print(dropdownValue);
            // getValue(dropdownValue,value);
          });
        },
```

json

```
'option': [
            {
              'value': 'Test Ride Period',
            },
            {
              'value': 'Demonstration Period',
            }
          ],

 String dropdownValue;
 List dropdownValueList2 = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    for (var item in widget.data['option']) {
      dropdownValueList2.add(
        {
          'value': item['value'],
        },
      );
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add the values to **dropdownValueList2** outside of the build method? Every time you're triggering a widget rebuild (via **setState**) they are getting re-added, causing the issue shown due to duplicate entries in the dropdown. I see your screenshot also more than one "Test Ride Period". If this is a **StatefulWidget** you could try adding it on the **initState**. If not, try to always clear it before adding the values again or something to avoid the duplicates. Can you try that and let us know?

Comment: okay i will try with init state